# How to write adb shell commands in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, appium-android

I wanted to pull some .db file from android device for automation testing which needs to

1. Open Command prompt
   2.enter the adb shell commands,
   below are the commands that i wanted to write in command prompt by programaticaly in JAVA,

```
adb shell
run-as com.sk.shaft
cd files
cp file.db /sdcard/download/sample.db3
exit                               
exit                              
adb pull /sdcard/download/sample.db3 C:/users/libin/desktop/sample.db
```

Till now i can open command prompt but i cant enter the above commands in the command prompt.

```
public class DBExtract {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Process process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /k ");
}
}
```

could anyone suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

Run multiple commands. When opening a `cmd` window you lose control over it. You could create a batch script, run it in a new `cmd` window and redirect the input.

You can pass the batch script after the `/k` parameter of `cmd.exe`. In the batch file, you can use the redirection from batch.

You are actually running two commands. `adb shell` is one command and `adb pull` is another. To execute "subcommands" in the shell from adb, use `process.getOutputStream()`, create an `OutputStreamWriter` on it and write the commands to it.

So, create a process for adb shell, redirect text to the input of the program and then use `adb pull` in another process.

If you want to see the output of the commands, use `Process#getInputStream`.

The program could look like this:

```java
public class DBExtract {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell");
        try(PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process,getOutputStream(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))){
            pw.println("run-as com.sk.shaft");
            pw.println("cd files");
            pw.println("cp file.db /sdcard/download/sample.db3");
            pw.println("exit");
            pw.println("exit");
        }
        process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb pull /sdcard/download/sample.db3 C:/users/libin/desktop/sample.db");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it does, now it opened the adb shell, but the another commands are not executing i.e. from here 
```run-as com.sk.shaft
cd files
cp file.db /sdcard/download/sample.db3
exit                               
exit.
```

Comment: You need to send those commands as the input of the `adb shell` command using input redirection (`process.getOutputStream()`) (I have edited my answer)